# C++ String Compare with Int

Tags: c++, string

i have the following problem:

```
do
{
    cout << "Type in something nice: ";
    getline(cin,test);
}
while (test.empty());
```

This code snippet will check the input if it's empty or not.
If it's empty, the same query will repeat.

Now i want to add the function, that the string "test" must be between 0 and 100.
How can I compare the string with an static int value?

The stoi function doesn't work here, because i have to use a non c++ 11 compiler

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert string to an int:-

```
int b = atoi(a.c_str());
```

then check if b is between 0 and 100 after making sure conversion is successful.

Comment: Making sure the conversion was successful is non-trivial here, as `atoi` returns 0 on a failed conversion.

Answer (score 0):

```
do
{
    cout << "Type in something nice: ";
    getline(cin,test);
}
while (test.empty() && 0 > stoi(test) && stoi(test) < 100);
```

Function Stoi convert String to Integer